# как изменить кодировку скрипта на python?

Tags: python, кодировка, pyinstaller

Как мне перекодировать код? Ошибка в pyinstaller с кодировкой, мне сказали, что нужно перекодировать код.

Answer (score 1):

В начала скрипта добавь: `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`. Или вместо utf-8 другую кодировку введи (которая тебе нужна).

Comment: я это делал, мне не помогало

Comment: https://mb4.ru/18-text-editors/notepad/131-windows-encoding-txt-file-notepad.html Левый гайд, но суть понятна. https://anton-pribora.ru/recoder/ или используй подобные программы. Чтобы дать более развернутый ответ, хотелось бы увидеть ТрэшБэк ошибки и команду которая его вызывает.